# Access and change values of an NSMutableDictionary from one class to another iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary

I am dealing with NSMutableDictionary in one class, But I want to change it's value in an another class.

Here is the code where it is declared.

```
@interface MyClass0 : NSObject
{
    @public
    NSMutableDictionary *valuee;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *valuee;
@end
```

and in the implementation of myClass0 I do

```
@synthesize valuee;
```

and I also declare value as

```
valuee = @{@"name" : @"Aryan"};
```

Now I want to access and change the value of this dictionary in an another class.

Comment: Use a dot accessor - e.g. `instance.valuee[@"key"] = @"value"`. Also, beware - using the dictionary literal syntax (`@{..}`) produces an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableDictionary`. Replace your initialization code with ` [@{@"name" : @"Aryan"} mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *valuee;
```

Now assign the value as

```
self.valuee = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

You can do this in the `init` method of your `MyClass0`.

Now you can access the value from another class like

```
MyClass0 *myClassInstance = [[MyClass0 alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = myClassInstance.valuee;
```

Comment: its create a new instance of it but i want the exact one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the getter by hand --

```
- valuee { 
    return valuee;
}
```

so the code *instance.valuee* will give you the original object not the copy.